# How to make python dictionary from big Javascript object

Tags: javascript, python, object

I have one string. which represents JavaScript object.
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1CFONQntMFMdtD-04rk9uut4UpLyB_OSsDH0bwDZ0tuM/edit?usp=sharing

When i'm using json.loads() python raises Exception: JSONDecodeError: Extra data.

What i'm doing wrong?

P.S.: It's dynamic object, I can't change him

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for

Things i changed:

1. Removed ' in the beginning
2. Remove extra / used for escaping double quotes
3. Added double quotes in the end

> {"log_timeout":1000,"featureFlags":{"serverRenderingForBotsOnly":false,"experienceLevelOnFixedPriceJobs":true,"JSUIPaymentVerified":true,"JSUI736SaveSearchRedesign":true,"JSUI341ProposalsFilter":true},"csrfTokenCookieName":"XSRF-TOKEN","csrfTokenHeaderName":"X-Odesk-Csrf-Token","runtime_id":"32a28ec0399c4e8a-DME","clientStatsDMetrics":true,"smfAjax":false,"pageSpeedMetrics":false,"ccstCookieName":"oauth2_global_js_token","pageId":"User","isSearchWithEmptyParams":false,"queryParsedParams":{"q":"python"},"jobs":[{"title":"Python
>   app engine, Linux,
>   infrastructure","createdOn":"2017-01-31T16:57:42+00:00","type":2,"ciphertext":"~01440d6a85cc997768","description":"If
>   you know python and have at least some knowledge of app engine
>   development. Willing to learn and positive. A big plus if you have
>   worked with the linux environment and knows how to set up servers on
>   google-cloud or AWS. \n\nWe can offer a job for a longer period of
>   time if you are the right fit.\n\nAt least 5 years experience as a
>   developer required.","category2":"Web, Mobile & Software
>   Dev","subcategory2":"Other - Software
>   Development","skills":[{"name":"google-app-engine","prettyName":"Google
>   App Engine"},{"name":"python","prettyName":"Python"}],"duration":"1 to
>   3 months","engagement":"30+
>   hrs\/week","amount":{"currencyCode":"USD","amount":0},"recno":209422776,"client":{"paymentVerificationStatus":null,"location":{"country":null},"totalSpent":0,"totalReviews":0,"totalFeedback":0,"companyRid":0,"companyName":null,"edcUserId":0,"lastContractPlatform":null,"lastContractRid":0,"lastContractTitle":null,"feedbackText":"No
>   feedback
>   yet"},"freelancersToHire":0,"relevanceEncoded":"{}","maxAmount":{"currencyCode":"USD","amount":0},"enterpriseJob":false,"tierText":"Intermediate
>   ($$)","isSaved":false,"feedback":null,"proposalsTier":"5 to
>   10","isApplied":false,"sticky":true,"stickyLabel":"Interesting
>   Job","jobTs":"1485881862000"},{"title":"Python</span>
>   Developer","createdOn":"2017-02-01T04:00:20+00:00","type":2,"ciphertext":"~019767ae6381e97a90","description":"Python</span> Developer who can read and
>   understand the legacy script and apply that understanding to an
>   existing Python business \nservice.  ... Python Developer who can read
>   and understand the legacy script and apply that understanding to an
>   existing Python</span> business
>   \nservice.",
>           "category2":"Web,
>            Mobile & Software Dev",
>           "subcategory2":"Other - Software Development",
>           "skills":[],
>           "duration":"Less than 1 week",
>           "engagement":"Less than 10"
>           }

Answer (score 0):

As @DSupreme says, there are extra characters in your data.

This can be caused from various reasons, one being stringifying JSON files and parsing in different programs and languages. If you need to verify if a JSON string is in a correct format, you can use verifying tools such as http://jsonlint.com/ .
For your specific problem, there is an extra `'` at the beginning of your string, `/` for escaping characters and  you're also missing the double quote in the end of your string.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in `{ }` at the end and begin of the string